# preg_replace_callback finding 2 matches should be 1

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have the following code being shown in a textbox and am turning it into a table:

```
foreach([-Order Detail List([-Order Id-])-]){{
   [-order_detail_id-]
   [-order_id-]
   [-account_id-]
   [-order_detail_assigned-]
}}
```

I'm doing the replace callback with this function:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(foreach)\(.*?\).*?\}\}/is', array($declaration, 'GetListPlaceholderConverter'), $email_body);
```

In the logic I have:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($matches as $match){
 $x++;
}
return $x;
```

$x keeps returning 2 even though it should be one.... Whats wrong with my callback?

var_dump($matches) is returning:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(153) "foreach([-Order Detail List([-Order Id-])-]){{ 
[-order_detail_id-] 
[-order_id-] 
[-account_id-] 
[-order_detail_assigned-] 
}}" [1]=> string(7) "foreach" }
```

How is that 2nd string getting in there?

Comment: `var_dump($matches)` will tell you why.

Comment: i edited to show the var_dump, any clue why it throwing that 2nd element?

Comment: standard php behavior. `[0]` in a capture is the entire string that the capture came from. [1]+ are the capture group.

Comment: So I need to return every other match if I want several pseudo foreach loops to show?